# Got 500 Request timed out for Kafka Connect REST API POST/PUT/DELETE

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to use Kafka Connect REST API.

Sometimes, I keep getting timeout issue for `POST`/`PUT`/`DELETE` APIs such deploying new connectors or deleting connectors (no timeout issue for `GET`).

The error looks like this:

```
{
    "error_code": 500,
    "message": "Request timed out"
}
```

Right now my solution is just waiting a few hours and hopefully it works again. Sometimes it works again, sometimes not.

I found a potential solution that if I set

```
KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
```

it might fix based on https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/issues/75#issuecomment-386400308

However, the topic replication is default to 3 for HA which is not good to change to 1.

Is there any other way to fix it?